# jQuery: Select grandparent's h1 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working within a really rigid framework (NetSuite) and there's a small section that I have direct control over which is the h3 and p text below. The structure is similar to this:

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <h1>Title Text</h1>
    <div class="otherstuff">Some text</div>
    <div class="parent">
        <h3>Text I have control over</h3>
        <p>More text I have control over</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the title text and the contents of '.otherstuff' for this page. There are multiple pages similar to this so I'm looking for a clean way of getting it done.

I've tried giving the h3 tag a class, then the following:

```
$('h3.myclass').parent().closest('h1').css('display','none);
```

and variations of that but without any luck. I've looked into the .parentUntil() function but I run into the same problem. I have no problem grabbing ancestor elements but run into trouble when trying to grab elements of those ancestors.

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: Thank you everyone for your time and effort in answering my question. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Where is `.myclass` element?

Comment: Use `.hide()` instead of `.css('display', 'none')`.

Comment: @Sarwic _"have direct control over which is the h3 and p text below"_  Does requirement allow selection of `h3` `parent` element `.parent`  ? , or only `h3` element ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't that clear. The '.myclass' was for the h3 tag.

@guest271314, I can select everything but I can only directly change h3 and p text through the admin panel

Answer (score 9):

1. Use `closest()` to traverse up to the grandparent
2. Use `find()` to select the desired elements
3. You can use `hide()` in place of `css('display', 'none')` as they are equivalent

```js
var grandparent = $('.myclass').closest('.grandparent');
grandparent.find('h1, .otherstuff').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandparent">
  <h1>Title Text</h1>
  <div class="otherstuff">Some text</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <h3 class="myclass">Text I have control over</h3>
    <p>More text I have control over</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for this very straight forward and clear explanation.

Comment: Does `.closest()` only travel up the DOM or can it go down as well? If the latter is true, how would I know which direction it will travel?

Comment: @TylerH, no it only travels up the DOM going each level until the selector is found

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two selectors that might work assuming you put `.myclass` back in.

```
$('.myclass').closest('.grandparent').find('h1').css('display','none');
```

or

```
$('.myclass').parent().siblings('h1').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Where is `.myclass` element?

Comment: Original poster said "I've tried giving the h3 tag a class".  It would be on the `<h3>`

Answer (score 2):

> have direct control over which is the h3

Try utilizing `.parent()` , `.siblings()`

```js
$("h3").parent().siblings().hide(); // `$(".parent").siblings().hide();` ?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<div class="grandparent">
    <h1>Title Text</h1>
    <div class="otherstuff">Some text</div>
    <div class="parent">
        <h3>Text I have control over</h3>
        <p>More text I have control over</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
$('.myclass').closest('.grandparent').find('>h1,>.otherstuff').hide();
```

`>` is for direct descendant element.

Answer (score 0):

closest() selects ancestors, what you want is siblings().

So:

```
$('.your_h3_class').parent().siblings('h1')
```

will return an array of h1 siblings of the parent div, and in your case the first item of that array is your h1.

And you can iterate through those and hide them (in case there is ever more than one)

Answer (score -1):

If the title is always immediately before the div with the "otherstuff" class, then you could use this:

```
$('.otherstuff').prev('h1').css('display', 'none');
```

Documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: I would like to know too. What is it that I did wrong?